# How do internal capacitor stud finders work?

Tags: capacitor, electromagnetism, magnetics, capsense, dielectric

I don't understand how a non-magnetic object like wood can be detected using a stud finder.

For instance, stud finders find wood from the dielectric constant, but I don't understand the principle.

The basis of my question is to understand how sensors can detect non-magnetic objects in order to build a paintball ball counter.

Comment: Don't stud finders detect the nails used to attach the studs?

Comment: please provide an example and/or more details

Comment: @PeterJ , no they use the dielectric constant of wood and a magnetic sensor which I don't know the principle of.

Comment: Is your actual question more to do with what the dielectric constant actually is? You talk about magnetic stud finders ("using a magnet and a sensor") in the body of your question, which have nothing whatsoever to do with internal capacitor stud finders (which your title mentions). Please figure out what you want to know about and adjust your question accordingly, else it may be closed due to being unclear.

Comment: @Madmanguruman. I edited it.

Comment: @PeterJ Housing studs have nails at either end. None in the middle. What kinda weirdo houses you be in?

Comment: @Passerby, not sure if they still do it this way but most older houses in Australia have a couple of horizontal 'noggins' that are normally nailed in place. Didn't word the above well but you can normally find those OK by running over the wall with a magnetic one.

Comment: What exactly are studs?

Comment: @Andyaka http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_stud In residential construction they are vertical structural supports made out of wood -- the walls are screwed onto them. I think commercial buildings may be metal.

Comment: @Andyaka Stud Finders is a double entendre ha

Comment: @passerby - a locating-agency for the girls eh?

Comment: @Andyaka and horses and bulls and dogs. Even cats. Breeding purebreds is a billion dollar industry. You can get a finders fee for finding a stud.

Comment: @Passerby wow I'm interested $$$ LOL

Answer (score 7):

There are several types of capacitor-type stud finder, see the excellent [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_finder) for more information.

The basic principle is that the capacitance of a capacitor of fixed geometry is proportional to the dielectric constant of what is between the plates. The drywall is a constant and can be calibrated out, leaving the difference between wood (dielectric constant of maybe 2 or 3) and air (dielectric constant of 1).

The seminal patent was US 4099118, which discloses a 3-plate capacitor design allowing the edge of the stud to be detected by differential capacitance.

[image]

That's the sensing principle. There are a number of ways of measuring capacitance, often making a ramp or an oscillator incorporating the unknown capacitance and measuring the time for a given voltage change or the oscillator frequency is an easy way, but there are others.

Comment: Can I use a magnet and a coiled sensor to detect the change in the electric field?

Comment: I can think of ways but nothing as simple as that outlined in the (expired) patent I referenced above.